# How to add axis labels for row chart using dc.js or d3.js

Tags: charts, d3.js, row, axis-labels, dc.js

For Bar Chart and Stacked Chart, we can use `.xAxisLabel("X Axis Label")` and `.yAxisLabel("Y Axis Label")` functions to add labels for respective axis.
But,
Is there any way to add axis labels for Row Chart?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
dc.renderAll();

function AddXAxis(chartToUpdate, displayText)
{
    chartToUpdate.svg()
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "x-axis-label")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("x", chartToUpdate.width()/2)
                .attr("y", chartToUpdate.height()-3.5)
                .text(displayText);
}
AddXAxis(chart1, "This is the x-axis!");
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/x5qb9/

I hope this helps!
-DJ

Comment: Do you know a solution without jQuery ?

Comment: tks.what do you have to change to add a label to the y-axis?