# Why dc.js does not support labels for bar charts

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have just started learning d3.js and dc.js.
I want to create bar chart in dc.js with labels, but when I refer the [api](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#labellabelfunction), it says .label function is not supported for bar chart.
Any idea why label are not supported?
What should i do to show the label just below the top of the every bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114336/how-to-add-axis-labels-for-row-chart-using-dc-js-or-d3-js

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature request for this.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/211

While I think I disagree with the person who downvoted your question (without commenting!) it's hard to imagine how this wouldn't have shown up in a web search.

For now I think you'd have to use a renderlet. Although I think I saw someone doing it, *that* didn't show up in a web search.

Comment: Hi Gordon, you are right. I tried to search before posting the question but could not find any results.

Comment: Well anyway it's a reasonable request and I hope to implement it or take a pull request (again, I think I saw code somewhere). The issue tracker is the right place to request features. Sorry if I was short!